# Running multiple JPA transactions in parallel

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, jpa, concurrency

I have two (or more) Java Threads creating, updating and deleting entities from a mysql database using JPA. To achieve this I have a PersistenceLayer class creating the EntityManager and providing save, update and delete methods for all my entities looking like:

```
public void saveEntity(Entity entity) {
    manager.getTransaction().begin();
    manager.persist(entity);
    manager.getTransaction().commit();
}

public void saveEntity2(Entity2 entity) {
    manager.getTransaction().begin();
    manager.persist(entity);
    manager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

If one thread enters operation saveEntity and the other saveEntity2 at the same time, both will try to get the transaction from the EntityManager wich will fail. However I always thought that the underlying database is able to manage multiple transactions, especially if both are working on different rows or even different tables. Of course I could synchronize the blocks, but that would mean only one DB connection is possible at a time which will not scale to multiple users creating several threads.

What wrong assumption am I doing here? Is it possible to submit multiple transactions to a database via JPA and let the DB handle concurrency issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`EntityManager` is not intended to be used by multiple threads. You need to obtain separate instances of `EntityManager` for each thread.

Actually, if you use EJB or Spring you can use a transaction-scoped `EntityManager`, which can be used from multiple threads (it's a proxy which delegates actual work to separate thread-bound instances of `EntityManager`), but I think it's not your case.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I am not using EJB. That is why I have to call manager.getTransaction().begin(). But your comment might be helpful anyways. Maybe it is possible to create an EntityManager per Thread. I will try that.

Comment: Please @axtavt i m interested in the Ejb transaction-scoped EntityManager can you link me to an example on how to use multiple threads for run multiple queries ? thx.

Comment: @frank, have you bean able to use multiple threads for run multiple queries?

Answer (score 2):

To handle concurrency issues when the object is being processed accross multiple transactions, lock can be acquired on the object. Either `Optimistic` or `Pessimistic` locking can be used with appropriate lock-modes.

Locking the versioned object by `entityManager.lock(entity, LockModeType.READ)` will ensure that it will prevent any *Dirty Read* & *Non-Repeatable Read*.

`LockModeType.WRITE` will force incrementing/updating the version column of the entity.