# Initializing EntityManagerFactory in a Multi-Threaded Environment

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa, concurrency, jpa-2.0

I am persisting entities over multiple connections to a database.  The class handling the persisting implements the runnable interface, and I create the EntityManagers in the run() method.  After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5966797/906048), I want to know if it is better to initialize the EntityManagerFactory in the class constructor or in a static initialization block.

Comment: I think one needs to inject the EntityManagerFactory then make a new EntityManager in each thread, since your application needs to be thread-safe as well, that's the solution I used for a similar requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you use JPA in Java SE - not Java EE. Moreover I assume that you have a class which handles the persisting of your entities - and that you mean this class when you are asking for *class constructor* or *static initilization*. Moreover I assume that all of your multiple connections targets the same database ... and I assume that you do not reuse your instances: neither your `EntityManager` instances nor your runnable class instances.

If the assumtions are correct then I would prefer to initialize the `EntityManagerFactory` either in a static initilization of your runnable class or in a second class which is implemented as singleton.

If you create `EntityManagerFactory` in the class constructor of the runnable class you have one factory per instance (that is per thread). This is is possible but unnecessary because you need only one `EntityManagerFactory` for multiple logical identical `EntityManager` instances.

Another question is where to create the `EntityManager` itself: in the class constructor (allows you to catch errors early in the initilization thread) or in the `run`-method. Personally I would prefer the `run`-method because it allows you to create and close the `EntityManager` in the at the same method using `try/finally`)

Warning: Be aware that you have no transactions across multiple threads.